# Visual Studio with Xamarin rendering display in designer taking a long time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I've been trying to put together a simple Androind app so that I can get familiar with Xamarin inside VS2015. When I open the default Main.axml file it renders in the designer properly and I can drag buttons and other items to it. But if I switch to source and then back to the designer it never renders again, the progress bar just sits there spinning.
The only way to render the page in the designer is to shut down VS2015 and restart it. The design will work until I try to switch to source and back again.

Using VS 2015 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

After an email exchange with Xamarin I have installed their beta version. The problem appeared to go away and everything worked properly. Unfortunately it still happens just much more infrequently.